# Twitter retweet but not mention

Tags: php, twitter

I created a bot to retweet one of my status in twitter... i used the api @ http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

```
$connection->post('statuses/retweet/'. $result->id);
```

i can retweet my tweet successfully but when i check tweet mentioning me, it doesn't list the tweet by that bot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retweets are not shown in mentions since the original tweet will already be listed. You can view the original tweet and see that it is retweeted or you might want to look at http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/retweets_of_me

Comment: @abraham the RT is not working for me neither :( $status = $oauth->post('statuses/retweet',$param);